# What does $|$ mean in the Schrödinger Equation?

Tags: hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, notation, hamiltonian, quantum-states

I saw the $|$ symbol in the Schrödinger Equation $$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}|\Psi(r,t)\rangle=\hat{H}|\Psi(r,t)\rangle$$  But I don't know what the $|$ means.

What does $|$ mean in the Schrödinger Equation?

Comment: Try a very basic web search for "Dirac bra-ket notation" will answer your query.  In fact as written the ket in your SE should really be $\vert\Psi(t)\rangle$ since the $\Psi(r,t)$ is actually a function in the position representation rather than a ket.

Comment: $|\Psi\rangle$ denotes a vector in a Hilbert space.

Comment: Either this should be closed (on the grounds of not making an attempt to look up the notation I think) or the previous two comments ought to be made into an answer I think (I'm not doing so because I'm not sure it should not be closed).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question shows no research effort.

Comment: How would you do "research effort" in any other way than by asking such a thing?

Comment: As @ZeroTheHero said, the correct SE would involve either $\Psi(\vec{r},t)$ or $|\Psi(t)\rangle$. But, moreover, you should be confused about both the $|$ and $\rangle$ since the $|$ or $\rangle$ individually doesn't mean anything--only the full notation with a state written inside $|\rangle$ means something. But, since you only asked about $|$, you seem to have associated some meaning with $\rangle$ on its own which is bound to be erroneous as it doesn't mean anything on its own.

Comment: @Pieter by opening pretty much any QM book and looking beyond Chapter 1?  Granted there is a bit of a catch 22 in the sense that of you don’t know what to search you can’t use a search engine but surely this notation is so common in QM that one can rightly be surprised at such a question.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this closure - it is in no way a fit for the criteria that make questions off-topic as homework-like. As for the claim that this is lacking research effort, if OP has misread the notation to the extent shown here, no amount of googling will help, and there's a whole lot of QM textbook to get through before they would get to material that would help them understand. Moreover, it's not our place to be "surprised" at newcomers' basic questions (CC @Zero) - our role is to answer those questions. We were all confused beginners once. This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Hmmm... This isn't a question about "what's a ket and how does this differ from a wavefunction": it's a question about "what's the meaning of the vertical bar".  I'm quite receptive to the former, surprised by the latter.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I continue to be surprised by the pressure to close question on SE.Physics. I have the impression that, maybe for a good aim, even questions which could teach something to many are closed very quickly. Maybe a period ef embargo, just to see if some interesting answer appears could be reasonable. Just to use this question as example. Apparently it is a simple question. But what about Dirac who, in the forth edition of his book, section 20, introduces the bra *without* vertical bar? Even if the OP does not know about that, would be useless for everybody else?

Comment: @GiorgioP *I have the impression that, maybe for a good aim, even questions which could teach something to many are closed very quickly* While it is true that there are good questions asked that are closed, the criteria for whether or not a question should be closed here is not determined based on the educational value. The guidelines are [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There are other places for questions that have good educational value yet do not fit to these guidelines. (I am not commenting on this question, this is more of a general comment)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: on reflection I think you're right (but I can't work out how to retract my close vote).  There's an argument that, well, skimming a QM text will tell you this, but I also checked both the Wikipedia [Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics) and the [Mathematical formulation of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics) & *neither* of them introduce the notation in any useful way, certainly if you don't already know the names for them. Also agree about things being closed to assiduously in general.

Comment: @GiorgioP There is a robust tradition of voting to reopen when the consensus on closing is not so strong.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero  Thanks, I know it and I have voted to reopen. The comment is basically to explain why.

Comment: @AaronStevens I have read more than once the guidelines, and if in doubt i re-read them again. I believe that this question is within the general item "Mathematics in the context of Physics" considering that a good and coherent mathematical notation is pivotal for Physics. Moreover, a coherent usage of the bra and ket notation is (notoriously?)  an issue in QM.

Comment: @GiorgioP I agree. Like I said at the end of my comment I was not talking about this question. I was addressing your concern about questions with good educational value being closed. I was just saying that questions with good educational value and questions that do not follow the guidelines are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Oh, boy, I remember being bugged to death by that notation for a really long time, and I had no idea what search terms to use. This one should stay open. It's interesting that OP managed to find the mathjax for kets... if I'd asked it, I'd have put > marks.

Answer (score 5):

The vertical bar means nothing by itself. The notation $|\psi\rangle$ is called a “ket” and indicates a vector in a Hilbert space, representing some quantum state. The corresponding notation $\langle\psi|$ is called a “bra” and denotes the Hermitian conjugate. Scalar products between two vectors are written as $\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$, with only one vertical bar.

Sometimes inside the bra or the ket you just see quantum numbers labeling the quantum state. For example, for the states of a hydrogen atom you may see $|n,l,m\rangle$ instead of $|\psi_{nlm}\rangle$, or for a spin state you may see just $|+\rangle$ or $|\uparrow\,\rangle$ to indicate "spin up". The idea is that you put inside whatever is sufficient to specify the quantum state.

Since bras and kets are vectors, you can operate on them with operators in Hilbert space, leading to notation like $\hat{H}|\psi\rangle$. When you take this vector-operated-on-by-an-operator and take its scalar product with another vector, you write it as $\langle\phi|\hat{H}|\psi\rangle$.

The Schrodinger equation tells you how the quantum state evolves, as a vector moving in Hilbert space that points in different directions at different points in time.

The bra-ket notation was invented by Dirac and is described in more detail in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation).

Comment: Succinct and clear. Explains bra-ket notation well. The best explanation I've seen TBH.